How to Install uv in one job and use it in subsequent jobs without reinstalling?
I'm working on a CI pipeline using GitHub Actions, and I want to install the uv dependency manager (GitHub repository) in the setup job and make it available for subsequent jobs (e.g., build, test) without reinstalling it in each job.
Here's a simplified version of my workflow:
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install uv
        uses: astral-sh/setup-uv@v5
  
      - name: Verify uv Installation
        run: |
          echo "Checking uv version:"
          uv --version

      - name: Debug Cache Key
        run: |
          echo "Cache Key: ${{ runner.os }}-uv-${{ hashFiles('**/uv.lock') }}"
        
      - name: Define a cache dependency glob
        uses: astral-sh/setup-uv@v5
        with:
          enable-cache: true
          cache-dependency-glob: "uv.lock"

  build:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use cached environment
        run: echo "$HOME/.local/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
        
      - name: Verify uv Availability
        run: uv --version

In the setup job, the uv installation works fine, and the version is printed successfully. However, in the build job, I get the following error:
uv: command not found

It seems the uv binary is not available in the $PATH for subsequent jobs. I tried adding the binary path ($HOME/.local/bin) to the $GITHUB_PATH, but the problem persists.
I've tried adding binary path to $GITHUB_PATH
- name: Update GITHUB_PATH
  run: echo "$HOME/.local/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

How can I persist the uv binary (installed in the setup job) so it is available for use in subsequent jobs without reinstalling it?

You can't. Each job runs in a completely clean environment, and those jobs currently run in parallel anyway.

so cashing cannot help me with that?

You can restore a cache in every job, but that likely won't be any faster than just installing uv. It's a binary of approx. 12 MB in size AFAIC, so this should take 1-2 seconds at most anyway - what are you trying to optimize?

Okay, thanks a lot. wasn't trying to optimize anything just tinker around. Thanks and cheers
